# Can't select checkbox using iCheck - HTML Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, icheck

I bought a stock image script and have a problem with the login screen. There is a 'Remember me' option with a checkbox. Unfortunately it's not possible to click the checkbox, only if you click on the string it will tick the box. I found out that the coder used icheck to create the button but I'm not sure why you aren't able to tick the checkbox.

Here is the source:

```
<div class="row margin-bottom-15">
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="checkbox icheck margin-zero">
            <label class="margin-zero">
                <input @if( old('remember') ) checked="checked" @endif id="keep_login" class="no-show" name="remember" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <span class="keep-login-title">{{ trans('auth.remember_me') }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Section

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-red',
        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the site in a live example: http://gostock.miguelvasquez.net/login
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: it seems your function isn't adding an onclik event on the right element, document.querySelector('.keep-login-title').click() is working but not this document.querySelector('#keep_login').click(), could you show us the iCheck function ?

Comment: Yes, sure: https://pastebin.com/LHS2ReEY

Comment: I edited my post, if you whish to see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i'm going to look at your iCheck function, meanwhile you could hack your problem with css :

```
.keep-login-title{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  padding-left: 26px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

Well iCheck is working properly, your problem is purely css, there is an error with your input, it should not be paint in front of your main checkbox which redirect each user's action such as onClick event:

Simply add this :

```
//you already have a .no-show class, i guess the author only forget the z-index 'thing'
.no-show{
  z-index: -1
}
```

In case you want to know more about [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the .no-show already exist
`.no-show {
    left: -99999px;
}`

I added `z-index: -1`, no changes. Still not working.

EDIT: Is working now! Thank you very much! (removed the left[...])